# Show that there exists $C_n>0$ such that $||f||_1 \geq C_n\sup_{t\in[0,1]} |f(t)|$ for every $f$ polynomial with degree at most $n$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $P_n[x]$ be a vector space consisting of all polynomials on $[0,1]$ with real coefficients and degree $\leq n$.

I am trying to show that there exists $C>0$ such that $$C\sup_{t\in[0,1]} |f(t)|  \leq \int_0^1|f(t)|dt$$ for all $f$ in $P_n[x]$.

My attempt at a solution: Note that $\sup_{t\in[0,1]} |f(t)|$ and $\int_0^1|f(t)|dt$ are both norms on $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, the vector space on continuous real-valued function on $[0,1]$. Moreover, $P_n[x]\subset C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ and so the above two norms on $C([0,1])$ are also norms on $P_n[x]$. But $P_n[x]$ has finite dimension and so all norms on $P_n{[x]}$ are equivalent which gives use (more than) the desired result.

I would just like to check if this argument is correct and weather there is perhaps a more elegant proof that I am missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $$C = \sup_{t\in[0,1]} |f(t)|\ $$ or $$\sup_{t\in[0,1]} |f(t)|\ \leqslant \frac1C \int_0^1 |f(t)\ \mathsf dt\ \mathrm ? $$

Comment: The second one is what I mean

Comment: In that case, I suppose $\|\cdot\|_1$ would be the $\sup$ norm and $\|\cdot\|_2$ the $L^1$ norm?

Comment: Yes sorry didnt, I didnt use the same notarion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argumentation is correct.